# set default landing view as classic

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic

In my Salesforce org, after logging in, the page is landing in Lightning view. Our org do not use lightning and every functionality is based out of Classic. Earlier it used to land in classic but after the latest release, we are redirected to lightning view. We are manually going back to classic but is there any way to remove lightning as default landing view?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is caused by [Scheduled Switcher](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_users_autoswitch.htm&type=0).

To control the Scheduled Switcher:

1. From Setup in Lightning Experience, enter <kbd>Lightning</kbd> in the Quick
        Find box, then select Lightning Experience Transition Assistant. From
        Setup in Salesforce Classic, click Get Started in the Lightning
        Experience Transition Assistant tile at the top of the menu.
2. Select the Optimize phase.
3. Click Motivate Users to Work in Lightning Experience to expand the
        stage.
4. Turn off Switch users to Lightning Experience on a regular
        schedule.
5. To disable automatic switching for a specific group of users, create a permission set using
        the Remain in Salesforce Classic user permission.
        Chatter Free and Chatter external users can’t be excluded from automatic switching using this
        permission.